# EclipseLink and Hibernate integration

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

we currently work with an Eclipse-Link project *(A)* and a filled database (with a sequence table).
for my next project *(B)* I want/need to use Hibernate to access and write data from/to this database. working with an entity that exists in *project B* is perfectly fine, I can save and read it.

*project A* entities are needed for *B*, so I included them in the build path. although when I try to save an entity from *project A* I get several errors.

**basic class Test in *project A***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;

public Test() {
}

public Test(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

// getter & setter
....
```

}

**class Test is added to my sessionFactory**

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure().addAnnotatedClass(Test.class);
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

**exceptions when I try to save a Test-object in *project B***

```
Hibernate: insert into test (name) values (?)
Nov 21, 2013 1:27:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
Nov 21, 2013 1:27:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2989)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3501)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.save(Unknown Source)
    at de.main.Dao.save(Dao.java:31)
    at de.main.Main.main(Main.java:47)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Unless you have a pressing reason to use Hibernate, I'd stick to Eclipselink for that database. Although technically they are both JPA compliant, in practice you'll spend ages fighting minor incompatibilities.

Comment: that's what I already feared would happen. I work with Hibernate due to my thesis and boss' instruction, the database was *supposed* to be **converted** to Hibernate by now, it isn't though.

Answer (score 1):

GenerationType.AUTO lets the provider pick what it wants to use, and this is different in EclipseLink from Hibernate.  EclipseLink will use a sequence table (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey), while I believe in Hibernate it depends on the database - but in your case it seems to assume Identity is being used to assign it or the key would exist in the insert statement.  Since your tables are not set up for sequencing or identity, you will need to specify the table generation that EclipseLink uses by default, something like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="testSequence")
@TableGenerator(name="testSequence", table="SEQUENCE",
            pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT",
            pkColumnValue="TEST_GEN")
private int id;
```

You will have to verify that SEQUENCE table and column names and values being used.

Comment: The above assumes that project A is running so that the database cannot be changed.  If it can be changed and the data in the database doesn't need to be preserved, just pick a concrete strategy and regenerate the tables.

Answer (score 0):

you've to tell you database at table creation to take in concideration the creation of the ID.

in the case of MySql :

```
CREATE TABLE `test`  
(  
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL **AUTO_INCREMENT**,  
 `EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)  
)
```

the entity should looks like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier")
public class supplier implements Serializable
{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 **@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)**
 @Column(name = "ID")
```

Comment: I have already tried to change the GeneratedValue strategy, no success so far.

Comment: What database are you using? Why not using a TableGenerator?